# Number of people are online in a website

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an ecommerce application developed in j2ee . How do i know how many people are online in a website in a given time ?

Is there any method in servlet which will do for that?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `HttpSessionListener` that way you may count how many times a `session` is [created and destroyed.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share why this was down-voted?  Was it the link to the 1.6 (as opposed to 1.7) docs?  IMWTK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use application scope (ServetContext variables) to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any authorization system? The best case is to count users are logged in.
If no, you can create your own session listener(see [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Servletsessionlistener.htm)) and store user information in set or map: adding new user on session create and removing the user on session destroy. You can store this information in some application scoped bean.